# How to add elements in span using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am having the drop down list by selecting the country sode the state drop down list populated dynamically using javascript

```
<div id="ddlState" class='selectBox'>                   
    <span class='selected' id="StatesID">Select a State</span> 
    <span class='selectArrow'>&#9660</span>                         
    <div class="selectOptions" id="stateSelectOption">               
        <span class="selectOption" id="ddlStateText" >Select a State</span>                
    </div>
</div>
```

on clicking country the state is populated for tht the code is below

```
$('#CountriesID').click(function () {
    var items;
    $('#CountriesID').removeClass("input-validation-error");
    if (!$("select#CountriesID").val() == "Select a Country") {
        document.getElementById("disableasterisk9").style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("disableasterisk9").style.display = "none";
    }
    var countryid = $('#CountriesID').text();

    $.getJSON(
        "@Url.Action("StateList1", "UserRegistration")" + '/' + countryid, 
        function (data) {                  
            var items = "<span id='ddlStateText'  class='selectOption'>Select a State </span>";
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<span id='ddlStateText' value='" + state.Value + "' class='selectOption'>" + state.Text + "</span>";
            });                  
            $('#stateSelectOption span').html(items);
        }
    );
});
```

the list is populated but the selection is not working properly it rendering all the state items in one span tag so for selecting any element all list get selected

I need that the individual element should get selected

Comment: just remove the 'span' here: $('#stateSelectOption span').html(items);
  This should be: $('#stateSelectOption').html(items);
And btw, you shouldn't use the same id for all items.  Try this:
items += "<span id='ddlStateText" + state.Value + "' value='" + state.Value + "' class='selectOption'>" + state.Text + "</span>";

Answer (score 0):

What see in the code on this line is that you are adding your html inside the span, so just take away that:

```
$('#stateSelectOption span').html(items)
```

The line must look like this (it will insert the code inside the div and not the span):

```
$('#stateSelectOption').html(items)
```

I tested it on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uz2vf/

Comment: By removing the span its not applying the class='selectOption'. Due to tht the selection is not working for the span